# Are there any libraries or samples for non-duplex WCF chunking?

Tags: wcf, file-upload, https, chunking, unreliable-connection

I'm looking for a way of implementing a file transfer service over HTTPS which uses chunking to cope with intermittent connectivity loss and to reduce the large timeouts required by using Streaming. Because the client may be behind firewalls, the [Chunking Channel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717050.aspx) sample on MSDN isn't suitable.

There is an [old discussion about this on the Microsoft Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/3724bcb8-dc04-47d4-a5fa-e89403b9e38a) but not a complete answer, or at least not one that I have the know-how to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sample of a resumable download service here: http://cid-8d29fb569d8d732f.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/WCF/Resume%5E_Download%5E_WCF%5E_1%20%5E52%5E6.zip

This sample uses a custom WCF binding. It looks like it works by getting a segment of the file at a time, with the possibility to get any remaining segments when the system is back on line.

Comment: Is it definitely non-duplex? i.e. you could use it where the client application is behind a NAT firewall?